# Entity Framework 4.1 - how to update, insert and delete data in derived classes

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a class called UserProfile, that derives from an object called User.

How do I insert, update or delete data from the UserProfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will define `DbSet` in your context. You can define set of base `User` type and it will be able to work with `User` and all derived entity types.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And using this is same as any other.

Inserting:

```
context.Users.Add(new UserProfile() { ... });
```

Modifying:

```
var profile = GetSomeProfile();
context.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Deleting:

```
var anotherProfiele = GetSomeOtherProfile();
context.Users.Remove(anotherProfile);
```

Comment: In EF5, in the similar case (with base class `Supplier`, `DbSet<Supplier>`, and derived class `SupplierViewModel`), I get `InvalidOperationException` with message "{"Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'ViewModelLayer.ViewModels.SupplierViewModel'."}". Why?