# Entity Framework 4.1 set EntityState on derived class throws Exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am facing a problem with EF 4.1. I am trying to Add a detached object to the DbContext. Problem is it is not the emd mapped object, but derived from it. Changing the mapping is not an option as some teams are using the model with the regular mapped BL-classes, but my project created a derived model for UI stuff. Even with casting I always receive a

```
InvalidOperationException ("Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType ...").
```

What I want is EF to treat this as the base class and put the object into the DbSet of the BaseClass. The current EF code is:

```
Context.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Added
```

But I am open for other suggestions, even
via IObjectContextAdapter, as long as it can save the Base and the Supertype. This should be simple, right?! Mapping to a new Base-class instance is not good idea as the main objects temporary Id would not be updated after saving...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know this is not possible. You cannot use derived class from the entity instead of the entity. You must either map derived class as well or create new instance of the entity for persistence and copy all fields from your derived class instance to the entity instance.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You answered another question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580203/entity-framework-4-1-how-to-update-insert-and-delete-data-in-derived-classes)) and it sounded like derived classes can be used. Is this not true for POCO/Detached/Whatever?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Is it maybe possible to override the current mapping? Using POCOs but not CodeFirst.

Comment: But in that related answer I expect that derived classes are mapped = they are entities.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarifying!